# Pytables ValueError: rows parameter cannot be converted into a recarray object compliant with table

Tags: hdf5, pytables

I am trying to import a csv file to pytables by first reading it into a pandas data frame, then doing some conversions on field and finally exporting it using to_records and specifiying the dtypes I want (I have tried saving data to pandas HDFStore but gave up as I faced a similar error). I have determined the dtypes, by using pandas dataframe dtype and for the object dtypes (strings), I have determined the max string length and specified that in my dtype when I convert the rec array before writing to HDF.

```
f = open_file('FLN3.h5',mode='w')

for num, chunk in enumerate(read_csv('DATA.csv',dtype=dt1, iterator=True, chunksize=250000)):

    #Some manipulation happenst to varioud columns

    print str(now()),str(num), "Completed Date Parse"

    df = chunk.to_records().astype(dt)
    if num == 0:
        f.create_table('/','df',description = df)
        f.flush()
    else:
        f.get_node('/','df').append(df)
        f.flush()
    del df
    chunk = 0

    print str(now()),str(num), "Completed Write"

f.close()
```

When I run the above code with read_csv chunksize=100000, the operations would proceed smoothly. But when I set chunksize to 250000 I encounter the error below. Note that when I would run with chunksize 100000 the records will be written well above the first 500000 records which indicates that there is no problem in the records themselves, also the numpy rec array doesn't throw any errors as the dtype for it has been specifically provided in `astype(dt)`. The problem seems to be with pytables write operation itself.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Thu Aug 22 15:50:53 2013 0 Read CSV
Thu Aug 22 15:51:09 2013 0 Completed Date Parse
Thu Aug 22 15:51:25 2013 0 Completed Write
Thu Aug 22 15:51:36 2013 1 Read CSV
Thu Aug 22 15:51:52 2013 1 Completed Date Parse

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/AIMS/csvtohdf2.py", line 144, in <module>
    f.get_node('/','df').append(df)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tables\table.py", line 2229, in append
    "The error was: <%s>" % (str(self), exc))
ValueError: rows parameter cannot be converted into a recarray object compliant with table '/df (Table(250000,)) '''. The error was: <>
>>>
```

Here's the tables.test() output

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
PyTables version:  3.0.0
HDF5 version:      1.8.10-patch1
NumPy version:     1.7.1
Numexpr version:   2.1 (not using Intel's VML/MKL)
Zlib version:      1.2.3 (in Python interpreter)
LZO version:       2.06 (Aug 12 2011)
BZIP2 version:     1.0.6 (6-Sept-2010)
Blosc version:     1.2.3 (2013-05-17)
Cython version:    0.19.1
Python version:    2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Byte-ordering:     little
Detected cores:    4
Default encoding:  ascii
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

Comment: Linking to the issue filed on github: https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/279

Comment: My current work-around for this issue is to write append to the hdf file in smaller chunks, e.g. df_part.to_hdf(hdf5path, hdf5_group_key, mode="a", format="table", append=True, ...)